# AWS Fargate vs EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am designing a solution For real estate application with microservices (Spring Boot) on AWS. For orchestration I want to use ECS with Fargate but I am not sure of it? I am confused which will be best choice EC2 or Fargate. and also more cost efficient. please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in using ECS in that case Fargate launch type would be better than EC2 because it doesn't require much maintenance and it is cost efficient.

For more information on ECS Fargate check this out https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-deploying-and-operating-containerized-applications-with-aws-fargate/